# OCaml function over polymorphic variants not sufficiently polymorphic?

Tags: ocaml, type-inference, variant, polymorphism

OCaml gives `` function `A -> 1 | _ -> 0 `` the type `` [> `A] -> int ``, but why isn't that `[> ] -> int`?

This is my reasoning:

- `` function `B -> 0 `` has type `` [<`B] -> int ``. Adding a `` `A -> 0 `` branch to make it `` function `A -> 1 | `B -> 0 `` loosens that to `` [<`A|`B] -> int ``. The function becomes more permissive in the type of argument it can accept. This makes sense.
- `function _ -> 0` has type `'a -> int`. This type is unifiable with `[> ] -> int`, and `[> ]` is an already open type (very permissive). Adding the `` `A -> 0 `` branch to make it `` function `A -> 1 | _ -> 0 `` *restricts* the type to `` [>`A] -> int ``. That doesn't make sense to me. Indeed, adding still another branch `` `C -> 1 `` will make it `` [>`A|`C] -> int ``, further restricting the type. Why?

Note: I am not looking for workarounds, I'd just like to to know the logic behind this behavior.

On a related note, `` function `A -> `A | x -> x `` has type `` ([>`A] as 'a) -> 'a ``, and while that is also a restrictive open type for the parameter, I can understand the reason. The type should unify with `'a -> 'a`, `` [>` ] -> 'b ``, `` 'c -> [>`A] ``; the only way to do it seems to be `` ([>`A] as 'a) -> 'a ``.

Does it exist a similar reason for my first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible answer is that the type `[> ] -> int` would allow an argument `` (`A 3) `` but this isn't allowed for `` function `A -> 1 | _ -> 0 ``.  In other words, the type needs to record the fact that `` `A `` takes no parameters.

Comment: Good reason, thanks. But as a side effect of "recording", this still causes good-looking expressions like ``(function `A -> 1 | _ -> 0) ((fun x -> (match x with `B -> ()); x) `B)`` to fail to type-check. Might there be a deeper reason? I'll wait a little bit more before accepting your answer.

Comment: What type would you propose for ``function `A k -> k | _ -> 0``?

Comment: gariguejej answered that below.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is a very practical one: 
In older versions of OCaml the inferred type was

```
[`A | .. ] -> int
```

which meant that A takes no argument but may be absent.

However this type is unifiable with

```
[`B |`C ] -> int
```

which results in `A being discarded without any kind of check.

It makes easy introducing errors with misspellings. 
For this reason variant constructors must either appear in an upper or a lower bound.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. Unfortunately I have no reputation to vote.

Comment: Oh, you are Jacques Garrigue. Keep up the good work! Just to tell you that I thought of this problem while reading the OCaml manual, section "Advance use". An complicated instance of this problem appears there, doesn't it. I read a blog somewhere which called that manual example "a major problem", so I just decided to ask.

Answer (score 3):

The typing of `` (function `A -> 1 | _ -> 0) `` is reasonable, as explained by Jeffrey. The reason why

```
(function `A -> 1 | _ -> 0) ((fun x -> (match x with `B -> ()); x) `B)
```

fails to type-check should be explained, in my opinion, by the latter part of the expression. Indeed the function `` (fun x -> (match x with `B -> ()); x) `` has input type `` [< `B] `` while its parameter `` `B `` has type `` [> `B ] ``. The unification of both types gives the closed type `` [ `B ] `` which is *not* polymorphic. It cannot be unified with the input type `` [> `A ] `` that you get from `` (function `A -> 1 | _ -> 0) ``.

Fortunately, polymorphic variants do not only rely on (row) polymorphism. You can also use *subtyping* in situations, such as this, one where you want to enlarge a closed type: `` [ `B ] `` is a subtype of, for example, `` [`A | `B] `` which is an instance of `` [> `A ] ``. Subtyping casts are *explicit* in OCaml, using the syntax `(expr :> ty)` (casting to some type), or `(expr : ty :> ty)` in case the domain type cannot be inferred correct.

You can therefore write:

```
let b = (fun x -> (match x with `B -> ()); x) `B in
(function `A -> 1 | _ -> 0) (b :> [ `A | `B ])
```

which is well-typed.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I made up the example with exactly that in mind. The problem is, in my opinion, that ``[>`A]`` is too restrictive than one would hope. But ok, since it isn't possible to express ``[>] constraint `A takes no arguments``, there's nothing we can do.